# Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement and ; Expected

Tags: c#

```
public string MessageItem (string ItemName)
{
    get { return dsMessageContents.Tables["input"].Rows[0].ToString();}
}
```

I am getting 2 errors:

1. Only assignment, call, increment, decrements, and new object expressions can be used as a statement, and
2. expected ;

Answer (score 14):

You're combining a method and a property into something that... won't work. :)

Use a method:

```
public string MessageItem(string ItemName)
{
    return dsMessageContents.Tables["input"].Rows[0].ToString();
}
```

Or a property:

```
public string MessageItem
{
    get { return dsMessageContents.Tables["input"].Rows[0].ToString(); }
}
```

[Read up on the differences here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229054(v=vs.100).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

This also happens if you use double `==` instead of single `=`.

```
string test;
test == "hello";
```

to

```
string test;
test = "hello";
```