# How to get refreshed datagrid realtime on C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datagrid

How to get selected automatically on grid?
I created timer but timer doesn't save grid selection. For example when I select grid's 3rd index then 5 second later it select 1st grid index. So I need other solution here.

```
private void formList_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{                
     BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();       
     DataTable _dt =_myFunction.Select_New_Inserted_Info(_lDataParameter).Tables[0];

     bs.DataSource = _dt;
     gridControl1.DataSource = bs;

     timer1.Interval = 5000;
     timer1.Start();
}
 private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {                  
      BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();       
         DataTable _dt =_myFunction.Select_New_Inserted_Info(_lDataParameter).Tables[0];

         bs.DataSource = _dt;
         gridControl1.DataSource = bs; 
        }
```

Comment: put ur timer controls code in the question..

Comment: I did in my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- If you need the dataGrid (and other binded controls) to automatically select the active Binding source's record use: `bs.Current;`
- If you want to populate the data every x of time, put your code inside a `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`'s '`Tick`' event.

**EDIT**

The selection pointer is handled by BindingSource.
so, you have to put the BindingSource outside the function
Your code will look like this:

```
        BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();

        private DataTable GetDataTable()
        {
           //Please consider checking the populating data function from errors, or post your code to help you with. 
            DataTable dt =_myFunction.Select_New_Inserted_Info(_lDataParameter).Tables[0];

            return dt;
        }

        private void formList_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataTable _dt = GetDataTable();

            bs.DataSource = _dt;
            gridControl1.DataSource = bs;

            timer1.Interval = 5000;
            timer1.Start();
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataTable _dt = GetDataTable();

            bs.DataSource = _dt;
            gridControl1.DataSource = bs;
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I inserted timer controls in my question.
I added `bs.Current;`  it goes: _Error 3 Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement_

Comment: @user2801618 Hi, I improved the answer to fit your needs, and tested it out for you and it works fine. if this worked for you please mark it as answer. and for the error you got seems like you are mixing the property format with the method format, please have a look at this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21592009/only-assignment-call-increment-decrement-and-new-object-expressions-can-be-u)

Comment: "r" - _The name 'r' does not exist in the current context_ 
And where I call select db function?

Comment: @user2801618 what 'r' ?!!, the select db function is the getDataTable function.

Comment: Hi there.  How to identfy datasource has 1 new data? May I use string.compare?

Comment: @user2801618, I didn't quite get what you are asking, anyway I would recommend you to make this question in a new thread so everything remains clear in this site.